# Create and access environment variable in bitbucket pipelines itself

Tags: node.js, postgresql, environment-variables, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to copy the env vars from a file to .env file in bitbucket piepelines, I can access these vars in code but not in pipelines itself. Snippet from my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file is down below.
$DB_USER is defined in env file but not accessible in the same step under services. This var is accessible in test files though. If I directly hard code the credentials it works.
How can I add dynamic credentials to access the database?

```
            name: Test
            script:           
              - cp .test.example .env
              - npm run test
            services:
              - postgres

definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: $DB_USER
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DB_PASS
        POSTGRES_DB: $DB_NAME
```

Comment: Any luck finding the solution?

Comment: Did you try putting them in quotes? "$MY_ENV"

Comment: Nope, I will try that sometime soon and update here.